# Gradle with intellij

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, build.gradle

I'm trying to open gradle project in intellij idea v 2016.2 but I'm getting following error:

> **Resolve Error**
>   No such file or directory

[image]

Comment: Make sure `/usr/local/opt/gradle/bin/wrapper` directory, all the parent subdirectories and files have write permissions for the user running IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: I don't have this directory. How can I install it?

Comment: Try installing Gradle manually and enable the **Use local gradle distribution** option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there was some issues with installed gradle distribution. After I updated `brew` and `gradle` issue was resolved.